# How do you return all matters where picklist option is null

Tags: clio-api

Is is possible to return all matter records where a particular picklist value is null?

I tried the following:

```
https://app.clio.com/api/v4/matters.json?fields=id,display_number,client{name},description,practice_area{id, name},custom_field_values{id,field_type,field_name,value,custom_field,picklist_option}custom_field_ids[]=123456&custom_field_values[123456]=null
```

I also tried setting it to be blank.  The api just returns an empty set.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is formatted correctly. The fields will be comma separated but then you did not include the & between the field and the custom_field_ids.